# Swing application for users not in Local Area Network

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

I'm developing an application which will use data from db stored in local server in LAN. I want also to deploy application for users which are not in LAN. So if I deploy app using Java Web Start can users not from LAN establish connection to DB? Maybe there is other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Only if you provide some way that the DB can be reached from the outside network (port forwarding from an edge router, VPN, etc.). Of course depending on how you do this, it will be reachable to everyone outside of your LAN, which is a security issue.

Comment: I would seriously consider making use of web service to provide the public face to the API/DB, thereby providing a layer of security on top of your database ... at least better then expose your database to the whole internet :P

Comment: The names gives it away: a *data base* is a component that deals with *storing data*. It should not be *server* serving user requests. In other words: one essential part of putting up a "server" is to **only** provide nice APIs to do exactly what is required. Versus giving them access to your data store.